# how to write this oracle query in jpa?

Tags: oracle, jpa

Query:

```
select *
from easquestionsinfo 
where questionname in(select questionname 
                      from easresponseinfo 
                      where isconflict = 'yes')
```

This query works fine and returns me the records from table 'easquestioninfo' when questionname is equal to the one returned by the inner query which returns set of questionname       where isconflict='yes'.

Comment: This problem is not directly related nor with JSF nor PrimeFaces.

Comment: You are right. But i want to show the data that will be returned by this query on an xhtml page using primefaces tag <ui:repeat>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA supports JPQL, SQL, and Criteria.

You can execute this SQL directly using createNativeQuery().

For JPQL, it depends on your object model, perhaps something like,

```
Select q fom QuestionInfo q where q.name in (Select r.name from ResponseInfo q2 where r.isConflict = 'yes')
```

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL